# How to pivot the table in mssql dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got the following table from `openjson`:

```
Begin Fixation   End Fixation
-----------------------------
 01.11.2011       10.11.2011
 01.11.2011       17.11.2011
 01.11.2011       29.11.2011
 11.11.2011       29.11.2011
 14.11.2011       29.11.2011
 18.11.2011       29.11.2011
```

How can I make it look like this?

```
[1.Begin fixation]  [1.End fixation]  [2.Begin fixation]  [2.End fixation] ...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    01.11.2011         10.11.2011          01.11.2011         17.11.2011
```

So, basically, each row from previous table goes to corresponding column in the needed one.

I don't understand how I should use `PIVOT` in this case. Could anybody give me a hand?

Comment: You'll need to pivot on the `ROW_NUMBER`. I *hope* this doesn't need to be dynamic. Honestly, this is probably a job for your presentation layer.

Comment: If the #rows is variable you'll need to search for and implement a *dynamic pivot*

Comment: Do you really want to work with such wide result set? It's no fun scrolling right to find some date in 2016. SQL Server also has a limit of number of columns you can select (4096). Many products like excel etc can pivot data themselves so you don't have to do this very cumbersome operation in sql.

Comment: @siggemannen I have no fun working with this at all :) To tell you more, i got the first table from json_values from another table. Now i need to parse it somehow to get the needed table and... insert it into the table where i get json_value from. This is the task I got on my job

Comment: SQL has a strict rule that it needs to know how many columns will be in the results _before looking at any data_. Since this needs to look at data to know how many columns you'll have, the only option is dynamic SQL, where you first run a query to find out how many columns there are then use that to build and run a second query that lists out each column you'll need in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```sql
SELECT  *
INTO #data
FROM    (
    VALUES  (N'2003-04-08', N'2009-04-12')
    ,   (N'2009-04-13', N'2016-04-29')
    ,   (N'2016-04-30', N'2022-11-09')
    ,   (N'2022-11-10', N'2022-11-10')
    ,   (N'2022-11-11', N'2022-11-14')
    ,   (N'2022-11-15', N'2022-11-23')
    ,   (N'2022-11-24', N'2022-12-01')
    ,   (N'2022-12-02', N'2023-03-01')
    ,   (N'2023-03-02', N'2023-03-05')
    ,   (N'2023-03-06', N'2023-03-08')
    ,   (N'2023-03-09', N'2023-06-07')
    ,   (N'2023-06-08', N'2023-06-12')
    ,   (N'2023-06-13', N'2023-06-18')
    ,   (N'2023-06-19', N'2023-07-02')
    ,   (N'2023-07-03', N'2023-07-04')
    ,   (N'2023-07-05', N'2023-07-05')
    ,   (N'2023-07-06', N'2023-07-17')
    ,   (N'2023-07-18', N'2023-07-23')
) t (cr_date,end_date)

DECLARE @cols nvarchar(max) = ''
SELECT  @cols = stuff(
(
        SELECT  ',max(case when r ='
            + cast(rn.r AS nvarchar(10))
            + ' then cr_date end) as ['
            + cast(rn.r AS nvarchar(10))
            + '. begin fixation]'
            + ',max(case when r =' + cast(rn.r AS nvarchar(10)) + ' then end_date end) as ['
            + cast(rn.r AS nvarchar(10))
            + '. end fixation]'
        FROM    (
            SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY cr_date) r FROM  #data d
            ) rn
        ORDER BY rn.r
        FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')

--print @cols
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select ' + @cols + ' from  (
            select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by cr_date) r 
            , *
            from #data d
            ) rn'
--print @sql
EXEC    sp_executesql @sql
DROP TABLE #data
```

I created some dummy data and put it in `#data-table`.

You build your pivot columns by creating a 1,2,3,4,5 etc counter from your table and generate the aliases and necessary aggregations etc.

Then you build your final SQL where you once again query your main table together with the counter.

The for XML stuff is just to "concatenate" all the columns into one string, one could also use `STRING_AGG` if you're running newer SQL Server version.

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer! I would have not figured it out by myself